# Room DB treating String @PrimaryKey as @Embedded

Tags: kotlin, android-room, annotation-processing, kapt

I am getting errors similar to below when I try to compile my project...

```
error: Cannot find a column in the entity com.example.BooleanEntity that matches with this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you can annotate it with @Ignore. - coder in java.lang.String
error: Cannot find a column in the entity com.example.BooleanEntity that matches with this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you can annotate it with @Ignore. - hash in java.lang.String
```

the super weird part is at the end of the error messages:

```
....with @Ignore. - coder in java.lang.String
....with @Ignore. - hash in java.lang.String
```

it is trying to access properties inside the `String` class??

my `@Entity` declaration is as follows

```kotlin
@Entity
data class BooleanEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id:String,
    val value:Boolean,
)
```

`BooleanDao` class...if i comment out the `@Delete` and `delete`, then error stops appearing

```
@Dao
interface BooleanDao
{
    @Delete(entity = BooleanEntity::class)
    suspend fun delete(id:String)
}
```

inside `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    .....
    // room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
    .....
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `@Dao` annotated class(es) as I suspect that the issue is with those classes. Also if you haven't added an implementation dependency for room-runtime, you should do so. Try commenting out all of the `@Dao` functions if it compiles then one by one uncomment until you get the ones that cause the issue.

Comment: @MikeT thanks for the suggestion. I will give that a shot!

Comment: @MikeT, you are a God. I was able to narrow down the issue to the `@Delete` function....and then I looked at the docs, and sure enough...I was using it wrong......the parameters should either be the whole @Entity, otherwise it should be a "POJO" whose fields will be matched up with the entity being deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented the `@Delete` function wrong.

according to `@Delete` JavaDoc, the parameters should either be an `@Entity` or a partial entity:

- > All of the parameters of the Delete method must either be classes annotated with {@link Entity} or collections/array of it.

  ```java
  @Dao
  public interface MusicDao {
      @Delete
      public void deleteSongs(Song... songs);

      @Delete
      public void deleteAlbumAndSongs(Album album, List<Song> songs);
  }
  ```
- > If the target entity is specified via {@link #entity()} then the parameters can be of arbitrary POJO types that will be interpreted as partial entities. For example:

  ```java
  @Entity
  public class Playlist {
    @PrimaryKey
    long playlistId;
    long ownerId;
    String name;
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "normal")
    String category;
  }

  public class OwnerIdAndCategory {
    long ownerId;
    String category;
  }

  @Dao
  public interface PlaylistDao {
    @Delete(entity = Playlist.class)
    public void deleteByOwnerIdAndCategory(OwnerIdAndCategory... idCategory);
  }
  ```

since the argument i passed in is not annotated with `@Entity`, then it was being interpreted as a partial entity....so it was looking for the fields from `String` inside my `BooleanEntity` class...